# WooCommerce - Modify checkout field's value when passed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am passing a `catalog_id` through WC's default order notes field. And at the moment it comes through as `{order: {note: "71"}}`

How I need it to look like is `{order: {note: "{catalog_id: 71}"}}`

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. I didn't realise it's only a label so just added this to my functions.php to modify the default value of the field.

Note: The value I'm fetching is in a session.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['default'] = '{catalog_id: ' . $_SESSION['catalog_id'] . '}';
    return $fields;
}
```